# In TypeScript, what does it mean for an import or export to be "top-level"?

Tags: typescript

The [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) say:

> In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a top-level `import` or `export` is considered a module. Conversely, a file without any top-level `import` or `export` declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore to modules as well).

What does it mean for an import or export to be "top-level"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The top-level in typescript is the outer most scope.

### What is a "scope"?

You create a scope every time you open a set of `{` braces¹.
Scope limits the visibility of variables and functions to the scope they are defined in and child scopes.

For example:

```js
import { something } from "<module>"; <-- Global / Top-level scope

function divide(x, y) { <-- Start function scope
  if(y == 0) { <-- Start of the if's scope
    /* 
     * Here is a child scope of the function
     * This means x and y are available here.
     */

    var error = new Error("Cannot divide by 0); <-- "error" is only available here.
    throw error;
  } <-- End of the if's scope

  /* 
   * The "error" variable is not available here
   * since the scope it was defined in, was already closed.
   */

  return x / y;
} <-- Ends the functions scope

var z = 0; <-- Global scope
```

This means:

```js
import { x } from "<module>"
/* rest of code */
```

works but for example:

```js
if (true) {
  import { x } from "<module>";
}
```

does not work, since the import is wrapped in the scope of the if statement and therefore is not at the top-level scope anymore.

But this does not mean the "top-level" is at the top of the file. It just means the outer most scope.

```js
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

import { x } from "<module>";
```

This still works, since the scope of the function ends with the closing `}` brace¹. Meaning everything after it is at the top-level again.

Everything said about `import`'s also applies to `export`'s

---

<sub>1: Sometimes you can omit the `{|}` braces to create a new scope. You still create a new scope, but do so implicitly.
For example, consider the two snippets below - They are the same. Languages create scope lexically - scope is not defined by tokens</sub>

```js
if(true)
  return true;
else
  return false;
```

<sub>is the same as</sub>

```js
if(true) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Top level `import` is the **static** import which is located at the very top of the file. Accent on **static**, it's called "top-level" not because it is located at the top of the file, but because there are **dynamic** imports that are not top level:

```
import foo from 'foo' // top level import, static one

import('foo').then(/* ... */) // not top level import, dynamic one

// no static top-level import can live here (after any code that is not a top-level import declaration)

function bar() {
  import('foo').then(/* ... */) // not top level import, dynamic one
  // no static top-level import can live here
  // no export can live here too
}

// no static top-level import can live here

export const baz = 123 // exports are always top level, and static

// You still can add not top level imports here, in the very end
import('foo').then(/* ... */)
```

Now, why this matters in Typescript?

Well if you put two files without a top-level import/export, that has two identifiers that are the same, you will get an error:

```
// a.ts
let foo = 1 // Error: duplicate identifier

// b.ts
let foo = 1 // Error: duplicate identifier
```

This happens because there are no top-level export/import declarations and TS considers these files to be `scripts` (in contrast to `modules`). And what happens if you load in a browser two scripts with same identifiers? Right, a "duplicate identifier" error will rise. Because both variables live in the global namespace.

Therefore, to avoid that you can do this:

```
// a.ts
let foo = 1 // Ok

// b.ts
let foo = 1 // Ok
export {} // This is the magic. b.ts is now a module and hence, is not polluting the global namespace.
```

Comment: `is a static import that is located at the very top of the file` that's not true. The line number of an import has nothing to do with being top-level.

Comment: @cgTag I wrote about that in the very next sentence. And yes there can be empty lines or `use strict` or comments before them, so technically they may be located not at the very top