# How to convert `require` to `import` within for loop?

Tags: typescript, discord.js

Below is a snippet taken from: https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html#loading-command-files

```
client.commands = new Collection();

const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    // Set a new item in the Collection with the key as the command name and the value as the exported module
    if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
        client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    } else {
        console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
    }
}
```

Within the for loop, we retrieve the command by doing `require(filePath)`. How do I achieve an equivalent behaviour using import?

The majority of the [Discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/) uses CommonJS whereas I am trying to implement my bot using TypeScript.

Comment: The short answer is that it's difficult. Maybe impossible. In modules `__dirname` is `undefined`, dynamic imports are asynchronous where require is synchronous, etc. You *might* be ok using `Promise.all` on an array of dynamic imports and then running the commands, but we'd need to know more about your use case. Frankly, I'm skeptical of the benefit of ES modules especially for server-side code.

Comment: @JaredSmith You can mimic `__dirname` by taking `new URL(import.meta.url).pathname` and removing the file name.

Comment: @caTS Yes, although it's annoying to have to do `import { dirname } from path; const __dirname = dirname(import.meta.url);` or whatever just to get back to the old status quo.

Comment: You could use the import function and resolution the promise `import(path)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: ***Dont!*** The require function works perfectly fine in typescript, and as the typescript will transpile to javascript, the es6 syntax is purely for the ease of writing rather than performance benefits.

The longer answer is:

Imports can be useful for modules, structures, and many other things, but not for iterations such as your for loop, where you would have to use the `import()` function instead of an `import` statement, which works exactly the same as a `require()` function aside from its asynchronous return values, making the `import()` function entirely redundant.

These are known as top level imports vs dynamic imports. Which you can read more on in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723621)

While you can not use the `import` statement this doesn't mean your command structure cant entirely adapt to es6 syntax. For example you may change your command structure from something like this with commonjs exports:

```js
module.exports = {
  commandData: new SlashCommandBuilder()...,
  async execute(...){
    ...
  }
}
```

To something like this with es6 exports:

```js
export const commandData = new SlashCommandBuilder()...;
export async function execute(...){
  ...
}
```

Both of these could be imported using the require function:

```js
const { commandData, execute } = require('./command');
```

I hope this helped you, and to sum it all up: Just because the option is there, it doesn't mean it is necessary.

Comment: "Which works exactly the same as a require() function" except that it doesn't. Because `require` is synchronous: it returns the module.exports when you call it. Dynamic `imports` return a *Promise* of the thing. So it's even *worse* than you suggest, and your advice to the OP is even more warranted, i.e. they shouldn't do it.

Comment: Thanks forgot about that, updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

`const command = await import(filePath);`

is how I do it and it works fine.

That is assuming your command files are using ES6 exports `export default` and not `module.exports`